# I need help with Clone(FClone) Brush

Tags: texturing

I need help with Clone(FClone) Brush in Blender,for some strange reason it doesn't appear,i tried to paint a new face texture onto the original texture.
What might i be doing wrong?I have attached a video showing what i'm doing.
Could some one please shed some light?

https://youtu.be/v-RCfvBaBWk

Comment: I'm not sure how the Clone Brush is tied here. There are some faces of the model which don't get the texture others do. You could select them (or all faces of the head) and assign them once again the desired material. This could be caused by deleting and filling these faces *after* materials' setup was done.